# How to create a huge Informix database?

Tags: database, scripting, informix, creation

Can anyone provide me with a script for creating a huge database (for example, 2 GB of data) in IBM Informix Dynamic Server (IDS) version 11.50.FC4 on a Linux RHEL 64-bit machine?

Comment: Do you need to create the server, or just get the data loaded?  Do you have the data to load, or do you need to manufacture it?  Do you have a schema you need loaded, or will any schema do?  How fancy do you want to get (ON-Pload vs DB-Access)?  Have you got Informix CSDK (ClientSDK) available - and C compilers?  Are you OK with downloading source and compiling it?

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2TB+ (nrows=10M, rowsize=2048) ascii load file (with pipe delimiters) for Informix which has unique: fullnames, adresses, phone numbers and a variety of other data types, like DATE, SMALLINT, DECIMAL (9,2), etc. for testing/benchmarking purposes.

Problem is - how can I get it to you?

Writing a script for generating a 2TB+ test file will not produce realistic data.