# creating large database 10gb for informix

Tags: database, informix

creating large database 10gb for informix

Comment: Please add some explanation or expansion of your question - otherwise, it will be closed as 'not a real question' because it is not clear what information you are seeking.

Comment: See also [How to create a huge Informix database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602255/how-to-create-a-huge-informix-database).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you ensure you have enough disk space allocated in the chunks for the dbspaces associated with the instance, there is no particular problem with creating a medium size database such as a 10 GB one. These days, a 'large database' really doesn't start until you reach 100 GB; arguably, not until you reach 1 TB. 10 GB is not small, but it isn't all that large.

Where will your data come from?  There are a large number of possible loading strategies, depending on data sources and version of IDS.  Note that the very latest versions of IDS (11.50.xC6 or later) include 'external tables' as an extra (and extremely fast) loading mechanism, and the MERGE statement combined with external tables provides an 'UPSERT' - update or insert (or delete) - mechanism too.